# Bind object's key to radio input's value in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm having an object in my controller like the following:

```
$scope.colors = {
    green: "Green",
    yellow: "Yellow",
    red: "Red"
};
```

I'm trying to create the radio inputs dynamically and then bind the value of the input to the object's key.

I'm trying something like this:

```
<label ng-repeat="color in colors">{{color}}
<input type="radio" ng-model="model.color" name="name" ng-value="{{color}}" ng-change="test()" />
</label>
```

but I can't make it work.

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mosmic/Xsk5X/1371/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to come with a cleaner solution.

```
<label ng-repeat="(key, value) in colors">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="model.color" name="name" ng-value="key" /> {{value}}
</label>
```

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mosmic/Xsk5X/1385/)

Answer (score 2):

You never define your model on the controller. I have updated your fiddle to do so: https://jsfiddle.net/Xsk5X/1380/

```
  $scope.model = {"color":"test"};
```

I also added a `<span>` which displays the selected color to show it is working

I've added a new function and variable - `$scope.createColors` and `$scope.colorsToBind`.

The function will convert `$scope.colors` into an array of just the object keys, and then create a new array of Objects containing the key and value for that color, but as accessible fields; each will look like `{key:"green", value: "Green"}`. Once we have the array of these objects, the function will then set the value of `$scope.colorsToBind` to that array.

Your html is now using that new variable `colorsToBind`, and is displaying the `value` of each object but binding to the `key` of each one.

Comment: Imagine this colors object is fetched by a server. I want to be able to bind the keys of the object to the radio input's value and make a post request with them.

Comment: Ah I understand now. I've updated my answer with a new jsfiddle link, try it now and let me know if you need more explanation

Comment: In this way you also replace the labels of the radios with the key values. I want to keep using the labels as before.

Comment: I've updated the link to the jsfiddle again. Now you use the value for display but the key for binding.

Comment: Don't get me wrong but I was hoping in a cleaner more "angular" solution. For example before changing this form segment to radio buttons I had a select list. In the select list in angular you can do something like this `<select  ng-model="model.color" ng-change="sendColor()" ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in colors"></select>`

However if not a cleaner solution appears I'll mark yours as the answer. I appreciate your spent time.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this also :

```
<label ng-repeat="color in colors">{{color}}
<input type="radio" ng-model="colors" name="name" value="{{color}}" ng-change="test()" />
</label>

$scope.test = function() {
   alert($scope.colors);
};
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Xsk5X/1382/)

Comment: This answer still submits the values of the object. I want to bind/submit the keys. e.g. bind yellow not "Yellow".

Comment: When someone picks the radio button with label Yellow I want to make a post request and send its key (yellow). The label and the value "Yellow" in the object is just a description.

Comment: ok @mosmic here I updated my fiddle, I added `$scope.colorsName` as an empty object, so when you post your data just pass this object so in ng-model it will send key of your color. may this will help you

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mosmic/Xsk5X/1383/ I added a span to show you that the issue still remains

Comment: you added `<span>` outside `ng-repeat` so obviously you will not get color outside it

Comment: span has nothing to do with ng-repeat. It just shows what the model is after clicking a button.

Comment: Yes but you are using it outside `ng-repeat` so you will not get `colorsName.color` outside, even it is used in `ng-model`,